# Angular service, how to have simultaneous calls wait

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-promise, angular-services

I have two controllers that want the same data around the same time, but I don't want the data binded.

So I have a service to go get user data that has this method:

```
var getUserData: function() {
    if (!angular.isDefined(this.userData)) {

        return new RESTUtil.getData('userData').then(function(data) {
            this.userData = data;
            return this.userData
        })
    } else {
        return this.userData
    }
}
```

Then I have two controllers that pull in the data for different purposes:

```
controller('ControllerA', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'DataService'], function($scope, $rootScope, DataService) {
    var ctrlA = this;
    DataService.getUserData().then(function(data) {
        ctrlA.userData = data;
    });
});

controller('ControllerB', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'DataService'], function($scope, $rootScope, DataService) {
    var ctrlB = this;
    DataService.getUserData().then(function(data) {
        ctrlB.userData = data;
    });
});
```

So the problem with what I currently have written is both ControllerA and ControllerB hit the getUserData service before the RESTUtil call returns, so i end up getting two data calls to the service.

I thought that i'd use a $scope.$on in Controller B to listen to a broadcast from ControllerA, but that binds the data.

Basically if ctrlA.userData = this and I change ctrlB.userData = that, i don't want the two userData objects to bind, they should be instantiated.

Any suggestions on how I can either a.) write my service logic where any calls to getUserData while a REST Call is happening will wait and use the same data call, or B.) have a broadcast that doesn't bind?

I saw a similar question posted here: [Have multiple calls wait on the same promise in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421123/have-multiple-calls-wait-on-the-same-promise-in-angular)

But i'm not sure how to leverage the $http since my actual webservice call is abstracted inside the RESTUtil.getData();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. But your service has a flaw. The first time it's called, it returns a promise. But the second time it's called (if the promise has been resolved), it doesn't return a promise anymore, but the resolved data instead.

The service should simply always return a promise, and it should initialize the promise the first time it's called:

```
var getUserData: function() {
    if (!angular.isDefined(this.userData)) {
        this.userData = RESTUtil.getData('userData');
    } 
    return this.userData;
}
```

If you want to avoid each caller to receive the same object from the promise, then return a new promise each time, that is resolved with a copy of the original data:

```
var getUserData: function() {
    if (!angular.isDefined(this.userData)) {
        this.userData = RESTUtil.getData('userData');
    } 
    return $q.when(this.userData).then(angular.copy);
}
```

Comment: Hi JB. Thanks for the comment. This definitely solves the promise issue, but this binds the two values. 

So if this.userData.data.name = "Steve" and I change ctrlA.userData.data.name to "Bob" it updates this.userData.data.name to Bob and ctrlB.userData.data.name to Bob.

I'm not sure how to unbind the service data to the $scope values doing it this way.

Comment: that's what I needed. Thanks again!